# Can't get nested if statements to work in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I thought i had gotten the hang of if statements and while loops in bash, but when i went to make a few nested ones, it flopped. I know I can combine these if statements using the (&&)operator, but for what I'm doing I need them to be nested. please have mercy, i'm new to bash.

```
while [ true ]; do
    if (( $INDEX >= 5 )); then
        sleep 1
    else
        while [ true ]; do
            if (( $INDEX < 10 )); then
                echo $(/Users/apple/Downloads/Code/graph.py)
                break
            else
                sleep 1
            fi
    fi
```

Comment: Are your `while` loops missing their ends? The syntax is `while something; do something; done`

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to do. If `$INDEX >= 5`, it'll repeat `sleep 1` forever. Otherwise, it's necessarily true that `$INDEX < 10`, so it'll run the `graph.py` script, then `break` the inner loop... but since the outer loop hasn't been broken out of that'll repeat and it'll do the `graph.py` script over and over forever. BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will have some useful suggestions (after you add the missing `done`s).

Comment: @WanderNauta ooooops, adding done to each loop did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @GordonDavisson the site will definitly come in handy, cheers

Comment: `while [ true ]` could be simply `while true` -- the former relies on the string "true" being non-empty; the latter relies on the *command* true having a successful exit status.

Comment: Please note @GordonDavisson's comments on your logic.   
Currently, there is only a `break` on the inner loop, and nothing inside the loop is changing the value of `$INDEX`, so it will loop and `sleep 1` forever.
What is the point of this? is it an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?